# attribute layout_scrollFlags not found

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

**Below is my XML file i am getting an issue. I am working on fragments and viewPager and its my first time term to get to this work so its almost new for me, i do not what the exect error is but it my be due to version issue what do you say do you have any suggestion???**
 *layout_scrollFlags (aka com.example.apex.viewpageadapter:layout_scrollFlags) not found*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            style="@style/MyStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you forgot to add required dependency into your build.gradle script:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependencies :

```
implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:x.x.x'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:x.x.x'
```

Then add the code to your fragment layout xml, like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure you have implemented your dependencies and xml correctly. That is it.